# Сортировка массива Java

Tags: java

Объявите двумерный целочисленный массив, в котором n строк по m элементов. Выполните генерацию массива случайными целыми числами из промежутка [a; b). Значения n ,m, a, b вводятся с клавиатуры. Переставьте столбцы массива так, чтобы их максимальные элементы образовали возрастающую последовательность. Выведите массив на экран в виде таблицы дважды – до и после перестановки.

Я все сделал кроме перестановки столбцов массива

```
    package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<List<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Введите количество строк n:");
        int n = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Введите количество строк m:");
        int m = input.nextInt();

        int a,b;
        System.out.println("Введите промежуток чисел от a  до b:");

        a = input.nextInt();
        b = input.nextInt();

        int[] max = new int[n];

        for(int i = 0;i < n; i++)
        {
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();;
            matrix.add( list );
            for(int j = 0;j < m; j++)
             {
                list.add(((int)(Math.random() * ((b-a)+1)+a)));
             }


        }
        System.out.println(matrix);

        for(int i = 0;i < n; i++)
        {
            int max1 = -999999;
            for(int j = 0;j < m; j++)
            {
              if((matrix.get(j).get(i) > max1))
              {
               max[i] = matrix.get(j).get(i);
               max1 = matrix.get(j).get(i);
              }

            }

        }





    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь таким вариантом сортировки:

```
Arrays.sort(ВАШ МАССИВ);
```

Если пожелаете воспользоваться моим ответом, то подключите класс из пакета:

`import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: Просьба написать в комментариях, если вам требуется не сортировка массива, а что-то ещё.

Comment: тут не совсем сортировка, нужно найти максимальный элемент в каждом столбце,  а потом переставить столбцы так, чтобы эти максимальные элементы образовывали возрастающую последовательность

Comment: @Blacit не подключить библиотеку, а использовать класс из пакета `java.util`....

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли Вам непонятно, как переставлять (менять местами) столбцы.

Видимо, затруднения в том, как это организовать.
Сложите максимальные элементы столбцов (а найти их можно в момент заполнения или первого вывода) в отдельный массив.

Возьмите код любой простенькой сортировки (например - выбором или вставками) и доработайте его - сравнивать нужно элементы из доп. массива, а менять местами - и эти элементы, и соответствующие столбцы матрицы.